# Possible to add tag to a static cell within a Dynamic Prototype UITableView? (Swift)

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a Dynamic Prototype table that also has a few static cell.  I am trying to allow one of these static cells to have two textfields within the single cell.  I believe to do this, I will need to set tags for each of the textfields.

But, I am not sure how (if possible) to assign the tags to the below lines.

TableViewController:

```
    case DiveMasterIndex:
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(Resource.DiveMasterCell)
        (cell as! DiveMasterTableViewCell).textField.placeholder = Strings.DiveMaster.localized // tag 1001

    case DiveMasterIDIndex:
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(Resource.DiveMasterCell)
        (cell as! DiveMasterIDTableViewCell).textField.placeholder = Strings.DiveMasterID.localized // tag 1002
```

The two TableViewCells

```
class DiveMasterTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate
{

@IBOutlet var textField: UITextField!

override func awakeFromNib()
{
    super.awakeFromNib()
}


override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool)
{
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
}


func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField)
{

    (self.tableViewController as! DiveDetailsNew2TableVC).diveModel.name = textField.text!
}
```

the second

```
class DiveMasterIDTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate
{

@IBOutlet var textField: UITextField!

override func awakeFromNib()
{
    super.awakeFromNib()
}


override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool)
{
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
}


func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField)
{

    (self.tableViewController as! DiveDetailsNew2TableVC).diveModel.name = textField.text!
}
```

Comment: According to the code showed above there are two different cells with one text field in each. Which of them is supposed to contain two text fields? And btw cell identifiers for different cells should also be different.

Comment: Ah, chaining the textfield name is enough to distinguish them?  Did not think of that.

Comment: OK, now I am onboard.  I need to add both textfields to the DiveMasterTableViewCell as this is the cell being used.  With the two different textfields names, within the single cell, distinguishes them...Correct?

Comment: Exactly :). Update your code afterwards if you still have any problems with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want one cell to have 2 textfields better way would be to create 2 outlets with different names for text fields instead of assigning tags to them. You do not need 2 cells for such case.